# PRISM DelegateCommand + Sample Data

Tags: wpf, xaml, prism, expression-blend, sample-data

I have a ViewModel that uses a `DelegateCommand` property to bind to a `Button`'s `Command` property.

The problem is my sample data does not like the `DelegateCommand` object. It complains that: `The type "DelegateCommand" does not include any accessible constructors.` Also, the only exposed property is the `IsActive` property.

```
<local:MyViewModel xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
                   xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism">
    <local:MyViewModel.Age>47</local:MyViewModel.Age>
    <local:MyViewModel.PurchaseAlcohalCommand>
        <prism:DelegateCommand IsActive="True" />
    </local:MyViewModel.PurchaseAlcohalCommand>
</local:MyViewModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your view model to expose an ICommand instead of a DelegateCommand.  DelegateCommand is  just an implementation of ICommand; if you later want to switch to RelayCommand from MvvmLight your view and your sample data should not have to care.

I'm not sure that this will solve your problem, but I suspect it might.  Plus it's just a good programming practice.

Comment: I thought about making my DelegateCommand private and exposing a "wrapper" property to cast the command as an ICommand, otherwise I lose the ability to make calls such as `PurchaseAlcohalCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` since it is not part of the ICommand interface without casting back to a DelegateCommand everytime I want to use it.

Comment: Oh, and I don't ever plan on using the RelayCommand since it relies on the CommandManager class.

Comment: This is typically how I expose my commands and I haven't seen this problem with sample data.  So I guess it's down to which problem annoys you more.  Generally I avoid other people's implementation of ICommand because of the issue you've found: it's difficult to tell the command object to update it's state.  Following OO design principles (specifically encapsulation), the command itself should know when it should update -- it should not need to be told to update.

Comment: Both RelayCommand and Prism's DelegateCommand are other people's implementation. RelayCommand just cheats and ties into the CommandManager.RequerySuggested event to raise it's CanExecuteChanged event, whereas the DelegateCommand exposes a method to explicitly raise the event. Though, I might go down the middle and expose the DelegateCommand as an ICommand through an additional property while maintaining the original property. So I'll just have to wrap one property as another to return it as an ICommand. `public ICommand MyCommand { get { return MyInternalCommand as ICommand; } }`

Comment: This didn't end up helping... Expression Blend recognized that the command was still a DelegateCommand in it's generated sample data, which makes sense because you can't create an `ICommand`. My sample data still works, but it is annoying that it doesn't hook into the ICommand using the sample data to enable/disable the button. Oh well.

Comment: My apologies, I left out a crucial piece of information: I construct my view models using the view model locator pattern.  The locator knows how to obtain a concrete implementation of a view model interface, but returns it as an interface.  That interface then contains ICommand objects.  If you do that, all of your buttons bound to ICommands on your view model will be enabled, but your sample data should come out clean.

Comment: I have no issue with my designer's sample data, and the buttons are all enabled. I was hoping it would enabled/disable the button based on the real view-model, but I guess that's hoping for too much.

Answer (score 1):

The way your `DelegateCommand` is setup, it won't do anything when it is activated. If that is the desired behavior, my suggestion would be to simply not declare it. WPF will gracefully handle being bound to a `null` `ICommand` object.

Alternatively, if you need it to bind to an instantiated DelegateCommand, you could subclass `DelegateCommand` to include a parameterless constructor.

If you wanted it to bind to a `DelegateCommand` and you wanted that `DelegateCommand` to actually **DO** something when the command is triggered, that would get a bit more complicated. You  would have to use the subclassed `DelegateCommand` I mentioned before, but you would also have to be able to define a delegate in XAML. I think there are samples out there, but I would guess they involve things like markup extensions and things of those nature. Your return on investment in this approach may be a little low, but your mileage may vary.

One last alternative that is the way this is *typically* handled: define your `DelegateCommands` *in the constructor of your ViewModel*.

Comment: Are you saying that if I subclass the DelegateCommand with MarkupExtension that I can get design-time commands to work? That is, if my sample data fails the CanExecute the Button will be disabled all based on my sample data?

Comment: @m-y: yes, that is technically possible. However, defining that same DelegateCommand in a default constructor of your ViewModel would yield the exact same results AND you wouldn't have to figure out how to shoehorn all of that into XAML. Just a friendly suggestion. I know this has been suggested to you a few times. There's good reason for it.